# Using yield statement for blocks when you have multiple arguments

Tags: ruby, block

The error message I get when I run this code is "undefined local variable or method `john'". Am I not allowed to define a method with arguments if I have a yield statement?

```
def greet(name)
    puts "hello #{name}"
    yield
end

greet(john) {puts "Nice to meet you!"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call as :

```
greet('john') {puts "Nice to meet you!"}
```

Corrected code :-

```
def greet(name)
    puts "hello #{name}"
    yield
end

greet('john') {puts "Nice to meet you!"}
# >> hello john
# >> Nice to meet you!
```

If you write `'john'` as `john` only, this will not be treated as *string*, rather Ruby will try to find it if any local variable or method having the same name exist. If not found, then the error will be thrown as you experienced.